# Rank-$1$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rank-1-matrices

I am struggling to understand the lecture notes (I have not learned linear algebra, but I do know some basic stuff). I understand the concept of rank of a matrix. A rank of matrix $A$ is given by the number of linearly independent rows/columns (same result). It is possible to find a rank by looking at the number of non zero rows in row echelon form of the matrix. A matrix is full rank if the number of linearly independent rows/columns equals to the number of rows/columns (whichever is smaller).

Now in the lecture notes, I have the following:

If $A$ is rank-$1$, then $\operatorname{range}(A)=\operatorname{span}\{b\}$, that is $Ax=\lambda(x)b$, totally lost now. And then the notes proceed: by linearity $\lambda(x)=c^{T}x$. We arrive to the expression: $A=bc^{T}$

Can I please inquire about what is going on there?

$b$ must be either a row/column of matrix, and thus range of $A$ is the span of that $b$, which is fair enough. But then I do not understand anything.

Comment: do a 2 by 2 example, the way they are writing it $b$ is definitely a column vector. So, do this: let $$ b = \left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 7 \end{array} \right) $$ Carefully find all 2 by 2 matrices $$A = \left( \begin{array}{cc} p & q \\ r & s \end{array} \right) $$ such that $Ax$ is a multiple of $b$ no matter what the column vector $x$ is. This is not hard, just write it out, multiply, see when the second entry is $7$ times the first entry; this gives some relationships among $p,q,r,s$ You can make it easier still, take $x = (1,0)^T$ in one case, get some conclusions, next take $x = (0,1)^T$

Comment: what kind of $x$ should I take? shall I say:
$\left( \begin{array}{cc} p & q \\ r & s \end{array} \right)$ $\left( \begin{array}{c} x1 \\ x2 \end{array} \right)$ ? That does not look right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s highly compressed and very sloppy; I’ll try to expand it. I’ll assume that you’re working over the field of real numbers. Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix of rank $1$. This means that $\{Ax:x\in\Bbb R^n\}$ is a one-dimensional vector space, so it has a one-element basis $\{b\}$. This means that every vector $Ax$ is a scalar multiple of that basis vector $b$, so for each $x\in\Bbb R^n$ there is a scalar $\lambda(x)\in\Bbb R$ such that $Ax=\lambda(x)b$.

For $k=1,\ldots,n$ let $e_k$ be the $n\times 1$ matrix with a $1$ in the $k$-th row and zeroes everywhere else, and let $c=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda(e_1)&\lambda(e_2)&\ldots&\lambda(e_n)\end{bmatrix}^T$. If $x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2&\ldots&x_n\end{bmatrix}^T$, then $x=\sum_{k=1}^nx_ke_k$, and multiplication by $A$ is a linear transformation, so

$$\begin{align*}
Ax&=A\sum_{k=1}^nx_ke_k=\sum_{k=1}^nx_kAe_k=\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\lambda(e_k)b\\
&=\left(\begin{bmatrix}\lambda(e_1)&\lambda(e_2)&\ldots&\lambda(e_n)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix}\right)b\\
&=\left(c^Tx\right)b\;.
\end{align*}$$

Thus, for each $x\in\Bbb R^n$ we have $\lambda(x)b=Ax=c^Txb$, so $\lambda(x)=c^Tx$. Now $c^Tx$ is a scalar, so

$$Ax=\left(c^Tx\right)b=b\left(c^Tx\right)=\left(bc^T\right)x$$

for each $x$, and $bc^T$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, so $A=bc^T$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the time you have spent to explain this. May I ask what a $\lambda (e_n)$ is? Is it some arbitrary scalar multiplied by $e_n$? So that we then have that scalar in the $k$-th row?

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: You’re welcome. $\lambda$ is a function from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$: it assigns to each $x\in\Bbb R^n$ a real number, $\lambda(x)$, such that $Ax=\lambda(x)b$. Thus, $\lambda(e_n)$ is some real number – call it $\alpha$ for a moment – such that $Ae_n=\alpha b$.

Comment: Awesome, albeit I still lack the deeper understanding about $\lambda(x)$ I suppose this will suffice. I very much appreciate your help!

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: Since $A$ is rank $1$, every $Ax$ is *some* scalar multiple of the basis vector $b$. The exact scalar involved depends on $x$, and $\lambda(x)$ is just a name for the scalar associated with $x$. You’re welcome!

Comment: Yeap, I suppose it is kind of intuitive. We have some rank 1 matrix, which means it has only one L.I. column/vector. Therefore, transformations applied to an arbitrary vector can only exist in the span of that matrix's column/vector. And that implies that given an arbitrary vector, the new vector is the scalar multiple of the spanned vector.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: That’s right. More generally, it turns out that the rank of $A$ is always the dimension of the range, $\{Ax:x\in\Bbb R^n\}$.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. So the rank is just the dimension of space where the transformation $A$ sends the vectors to? (unsure about the correctness of my evaluation there). I wish this was just one unknown in the lecture notes. There are still tons more, among which is SVD. I have already read up a lot on it.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: Yes, the rank of $A$ is the dimension of the subspace of $\Bbb R$ onto which $A$ sends the domain. In fact, that subspace is precisely the column space of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

If it really said $Ax = \text{span}\{b\}$, that would be wrong.  More likely is
$Ax \in \text{span}\{b\}$, i.e. (for every column vector $x$ of the right dimension) $Ax$ is a multiple of the column vector $b$.  That means there is some function $\lambda$ on $\mathbb R^n$ (the space of $n$-component column vectors with real entries) such that $\lambda(x)$ tells which multiple of $b$  is $A x$.  This is a linear function, i.e. $\lambda(s x + t y) = s \lambda(x) + t \lambda(y)$ for any vectors $x$ and $y$ and scalars $s$ and $t$.  Every linear function on $\mathbb R^n$ is of the form $\lambda(x) = c^T x$ where $c$ is some $n$-component row vector. 
Then $A x = (c^T x) b = (b c^T) x$.

Comment: my bad. Just corrected it.